# Does the openFDA drug adverse events dataset (or any other dataset) have a geographic dimension?

Tags: openfda, api

I want to produce visualizations of PRR and ROR of drug adverse events using openFDA data using d3 and shiny. I want to build interactive map view (map of the US with PRR values by state, for example). Does the openFDA drug adverse events report dataset (or the source dataset) have a spatial (geographic) dimension?

Comment: NB. I am interested in data for the USA but at a spatial resolution of by state or finer.

Answer (score 1):

The drug events endpoint (open.fda.gov/drug/event/reference) does have a geographic component.. but it is at the country level (see `occurcountry`, `primarysourcecountry`, and `primarysource.reportercountry`)

http://www.fda.gov/Drugs/GuidanceComplianceRegulatoryInformation/Surveillance/AdverseDrugEffects/ has more information about the source systems that feed into FAERS and eventually openFDA